# Why does BufferedReader return null in first row?

Tags: java, methods, null, bufferedreader

This is my method. You input a String and it will basically split the string up in to parts storing them inside an Array.

I am trying to do this to a certain String. Whenever it finds "*" in a row, it needs to stop and store it. It works perfectly, except that on the first line it always prints "null". I don't know why and I don't know how to get rid of this. Would very much appreciate if someone could explain.

```
public static String[] splitWeeks(String t)throws IOException {
    String[] weeks = new String[4];
    
    //Create Stream from 
    BufferedReader instream = new BufferedReader (new StringReader(t));
    //loop that picks out each week
    for(int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        while (true) {
            //Store current row being read in variable
            String row = instream.readLine();
            weeks[i] = weeks[i] +  row + "\n";
            if ( row.equals("*")||  row == null) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return weeks;
}
```

This prints almost what I want, just that it says "null" in the beginning. How do I fix this?

Print:

```
/*
nullMONDAY WEEK 4 Quads=3, Calfes=2, Abs=3
Legs: 
3x Quads
2x Calfes
Abs: 
LegRaise-LayingDown-GripSupport
Your choice
Abs Side: 
Woodchopper (testing)
*
*/
```

I tried to change the while looop to `while (instream.readLine() !=null || instream.readLine() == "*")`, with no luck.

Comment: `row` isn't null in the code you've shown, or you'd have a `NullPointerException` on the next line. However, `weeks[i]` *will* be null, and that's where the `null` is coming from in `weeks[i] +  row + "\n"`. Note that this would have been clear if you'd stepped through the code in the debugger. If you haven't used a debugger before, I'd strongly recommend setting some time aside to learn about debugging. It'll save you a lot of time in the future.

Comment: (Note that your code is still broken in that if `row` *is* null, it'll throw an exception rather than breaking... you need to reverse the order of your comparisons, i.e. `if (row == null || row.equals("*"))`

Comment: But I think primary problem (description) can be solved via: `t.replaceAll("null", "")` !?

Comment: @xerx593: Not if the OP wants to actually preserve data that may genuinely include the word "null". It would be much better to create a `StringBuilder` and append to that in the loop, instead of using `weeks[i] = weeks[i] +  row + "\n";`. That would be more efficient, more idiomatic IMO, fix the problem, and not lose data.

Comment: Maybe I just don't get it/tldr :) A sample input for `t` would make things (much) clearer..

Comment: `readLine()` of `BufferedReader` only returns `null` when it has reached the end of stream (end of file).

Comment: Thank you I was able to solve it with ```.replaceAll("null", "");```

I am unsettled that my question got many dislikes. I don't know what a debugger is and will look in to it a bit more. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

On initialize the String array, it values are all null.
The first time to adding some string, the null value converted by toString() to concatenate with other. Initialize your array with `""` values before using. (Before while.. put this line: `weeks[i] = "";`)

Another maybe an easier solution:

```
String[] result = t.split("\\*");
```

Comment: Thank you I was able to solve it with ```.replaceAll("null", "");```

I am unsettled that my question got many dislikes. I don't know what a debugger is and will look in to it a bit more. Thank you all.

Comment: @ownsgood Keep in mind: you made a mistake with array initialized by null values and working with it. Solving this after running with `replaceAll` is far from the best practice. Even better if you prevent such situations. In other cases this will lead to a NullPointerException error.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I just do not seem to understand despite people pinpointing it out where I made that mistake. 

So to the best of my understanding I made a null when I initiated the weeks[i] array the first time. I somehow did it wrong ? I agree and appreciate the advice that this might be a inefficient practice in the long run.

Comment: @ownsgood What you have made wrong: When you initialized an array of objects `String[] weeks = new String[4];` it contains null values. (String is object). When you use an item of array first time: `weeks[i] = weeks[i] +  row + "\n";` then `weeks[i]` is `null`, and that was the mistake. If other situations this array contains ie. your own created object that have not default toString() method or you want make other operation ie. call some method of the object `weeks[i].concat()` then you run into a NullPointerException error. Learn java programming basics a bit more deeper.

Comment: Thank you for an outstanding answer ! I understand now. Creating objects and what objects are is  next chapter in my book. So hopefully I will learn more about that and hopefully it will help me to understand similar things to prevent issues like these to happen. I thank you @szeak